# Splash screen windows are very small

Tags: windows, windows-10, resolution

Certain windows such as splash screens render very small and are almost unreadable in relation to other areas of screen :

[image]

Starcraft window above is barely readable.

Is this a resolution issue ?

Update :

Resolution (3200 x 1800) :

[image]

Another example, this time screenshot of Anki, main text is hardly visible :

[image]

My display settings :

[image]

I think this may be due to apps not packaging suitable artifacts for high resolution displays ?

Comment: Please indicate the resolution that the monitor/system is in , and your DPI settings, to further understand what we are seeing here?

Comment: @Psycogeek sorry about delay, please see question update.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, this is a result of the resolution you are using.

Windows scales its window objects and fonts so that they look roughly the same on 800x600 and 2560x1440 or whatever display you chose. This works pretty well, though it can have some issues.

In the case of the starcraft launcher, its a bespoke window written by Blizzard that doesnt use a regular windows element, so they must implement their own scaling, which they haven't.